# How did they come to this parameterization of an ellipse?

Tags: calculus, integration, conic-sections, parametrization, line-integrals

The topic is about line integrals,
the question:

Calculate $\int_\gamma \vec x \cdot d\vec s$ for

$\vec v = (0,xy^2)$ and $\gamma$ die ellipse with the equation $x^2+(y/2)^2=1$ once to go counter clockwise

then they give the answer for the parameterization as:

$\gamma :[0, 2\pi]\to \Bbb R^2, t \to (\cos t, 2 \sin t)$

my question is, how did they find the parameterization to be $(\cos t , 2 \sin t)$

Comment: If $a$ and $b$ are the minor and major axes of your ellipse you are trying to find $x = a\cos \theta$ and $y=b \sin \theta$ so you have polar co-ords for your ellipse and $x^2 + (y/2)^2 =1 $.  Solve for $a$ and $b$

Comment: I sadly do not understand, how can i solve for $a$ and $b$ if i only have one equation and not two.

Comment: $a^2 \cos^2 \theta + (b^2 \sin^2 \theta)/4 = 1$ and $\cos^2 \theta + \sin^2 \theta =1$ so a solution must be $a=1$ and $b=\pm 2$  Clearly the axis of an ellipse can't be negative so you get $a=1, b=2$.  This does not guarantee this is the only solution, but when you're finding a parametrisation this is good enough to start with.

Comment: Let $X=x$, $Y=y/2$. $X^2+Y^2=1 \Rightarrow X=\cos t, Y=\sin t$ (well-known parametrization of circle). Then $x=\cos t$, $y=2\sin t$.